# Exclude UICulture string (ex: en-US) from URL generated by UrlHelper.Action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Firstly, my testing website URL is

```
http://localhost:51889/MVTS
```

Despite my CurrentUICulture string not being present in the above URL, when I declare a `@Url.Action("ActionOne","User")` in my Main.cshtml, the UI culture string exists in my script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/MVTS/en-US/User/ActionOne'></script>
```

What I wish to do is to be able to exclude the "en-US" so that the "src" in the above tag looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/MVTS/User/ActionOne'></script>
```

Can anyone please tell me how I may accomplish this? I have been searching for a while and haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your routes definition. Probably you have a rule with an attribute like `{culture}`.

You can delete that attribute or, if you need it in other sections of your application, you can add another route definition without the culture and, in place of `Url.Action`, you can use `Url.RouteUrl` (giving, as a parameter, the name of the route definition).

Comment: The {culture} is not present in the routes definition. I tried using Url.RouteUrl(routeName) as well as Url.RouteValues(routeName, routeValues). It didn't help though. :(

Comment: Can you give us the routes definition(s)

Answer (score 0):

My solution turned out to be a different one. It turns out that since my Controller was in an "Area" named as "Admin", it was in my interests to add the {lang} as

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "{lang}/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Although this solves the issue I was having, the answer given by [Fabio S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2496767/fabio-s) is the correct solution to the question asked. And so I am marking his answer as the correct one.